# Show a list of users logged in, (passportjs, sessions, maybe sockets)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, authentication, facebook-login

**Intro:**

Okay I have put together a nice app allowing users to login (node.js, passportjs, mongodb). Now furthering the app, I need to see who is logged in.

---

**Theory:**

So this idea just hit me, I think the best idea would be to pass a `connected = true`, or `connected = false` when a user logs in, and logs out to the user model.

---

**Question:**

My question is what is the best way to track who's sessions are active/connected/loggedin within my app? Would it be passing in those properties to the model?

Is there be a standard way for tracking the sessions of all the users? I don't want this to be an opinionated question which is against the rules, but there has to be a technical way to track the sessions! What would be best practices for something like this?

---

**Trials:**

So here I can be more specific I put it to the test and I forgot inside my handlebars template I can only access properties from that users mongodb model.

```
<div class="row">

    {{#if user.connected}}
        {{#each user.connected}}
            <li>{{this}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    {{/if}}

</div>
```

The above obviously doesn't work, because the data is passed like this when the route for that page is made.

```
res.render('profile', { user : req.user });
```

So I am sticking with the `connected: true`, `connected: false` it's easy, works, and makes sense to me.

---

**Refined question:**

So with the given, I am routing using express, rendering and passing the response object to my handlebars template. I want to create a model that has `admin = true` and only should that user get access to all the models.

My question is in the response object how can I pass a collection of all the users. It wouldn't work as a response, I may need to do a mongoDB query? Does that sound right, something like

```
AppUser.find({ connected: true }, function (err, user) {
    console.log(user);
    res.render('profile', { user : user });
});
```

Something like the above, I am going to test it and post back. I feel I have narrowed it down, so what would be the best solution in passing a list of all connected models to the "res.render" so that I can access them in my template?

---

**Edit:** So this sort of works, here is a problem I am running into.

I want to be able to render the user like this `res.render('chat', { user : req.user })` but I also want to render a list of the users if the `req.user` is an admin. So off the top of the head I am thinking to pass two objects.

```
AppUser.find({}, function (err, users) {
    console.log(users); 
    res.render('profile', { user: req.user, users : users }); 
});
```

Handlebars

```
<div class="row">

    {{#each users}}
        {{#if this.connected}}
            <li><b>Connected:</b> {{this.connected}}</li>
            {{#if this.facebook.email}}
                <li><b>Email:</b> {{this.facebook.email}}</li>
            {{else}}
                <li><b>Email:</b> {{this.local.email}}</li>    
            {{/if}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}

</div>
```

^^^ Works! :) any thoughts?

Comment: I'm have the same question did find a way?

Comment: Is keeping a `JSON` of connected users not an option? e.g. `let jsonObj = {}; jsonObj[user].connected = true; ` and access it in your `passport.deserializeUser function`